# NSFetchedResultsController "out of order section name'

Tags: uitableview, core-data, nsfetchrequest, nsfetchedresultscontroller, magicalrecord

I'm using `MagicalRecord` to fetch my data. In my app I have a list of contact that are grouped into contact groups. I am displaying these contact groups in a grouped `UITableView`.

For example, I have the following (which is what I expect):

```m
Default Groups  // section header
[Everyone]      // cell row
[Favourites]    // cell row

My Group        // section header
[Coworkers]     // cell row
```

Sometimes my groups get mixed up:

```m
Default Groups  // section header
[Everyone]      // cell row
[Coworkers]     // cell row

My Group        // section header
[Favourites]    // cell row
```

Each Contact group name and group type that I use to sort and group by. Group type is an integer. When I check their attributes they do in fact have the correct group type.

My FRC looks like this:

```m
fetchedResultsController = [ContactGroup fetchAllSortedBy:@"groupName"
                                                ascending:YES
                                            withPredicate:nil
                                                  groupBy:@"groupType"
                                                 delegate:self];
```

I see the following error:

```m
CoreData: error: (NSFetchedResultsController) The fetched object at index 2 has an out of order section name '1. Objects must be sorted by section name'
+[MagicalRecord(ErrorHandling) defaultErrorHandler:](0x2eefb8) Error: The fetched object at index 2 has an out of order section name '1. Objects must be sorted by section name'
+[MagicalRecord(ErrorHandling) defaultErrorHandler:](0x2eefb8) Error Message: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134060.)
+[MagicalRecord(ErrorHandling) defaultErrorHandler:](0x2eefb8) Error Domain: NSCocoaErrorDomain
+[MagicalRecord(ErrorHandling) defaultErrorHandler:](0x2eefb8) Recovery Suggestion: (null)
```

Please let me know if I need to provide more details, I am kind of stumped at this point and not 100% sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Not having used MagicalRecord, can you set multiple sort criteria?

I'm assuming it's using groupBy: as the section name so in that case, I'd have two sort descriptors, one for 'groupType' and then the second one for 'groupName'.

That will sort the sections in the right sequence and then everything in the right order inside the sections.